# Perl DBD::SQLite - begin_work outside while loop blocks threads?

Tags: multithreading, perl, sqlite, loops, dbi

I have a script that creates a number of threads using the Perl threads module, and each thread is creating a db connection to an SQLite dbfile. Inside the threads there is a while loop reading from a filehandle that opens a piped input to a file being processed with zcat. I'm trying to commit transactions every X rows being processed per thread. When I try to use `$dbh->begin_work` outside of the while loop a single thread blocks the rest. When I put `$dbh->begin_work` inside the while loop they do not block each other. The latter is essentially autocommiting each `$dbh->do("insert...")` statement. Why does `$dbh->begin_work` appear not to work outside of the while loop?

```
$dbh->begin_work; # This blocks the while loops in other threads

while ($row = <$gz>) {
  $dbh->begin_work; # This does not block
  @values = split('\|', $row);
  @node_ids = split ',', $values[21]
  for $node_id (@node_ids) {
    $dbh->do("insert ....");
  }
  $dbh->commit; # This does not block
}

$dbh->commit; # This blocks the while loops in other threads
```

I'm currently using DBD:SQLite version 1.29. I tried using *sqlite_use_immediate_transaction* but that doesn't seem to be necessary until version 1.38_01.

Comment: Please provide an actual demonstration of the problem. Also, make sure you crate the dbh in the thread that uses it. If that doesn't help, it could be a SQLite limitation.

Comment: Have you checked the SQLite docs on threads? https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html

Answer (score 0):

All my locking experience is in other databases and I am not sure what you are expecting (it seems to me that begin_work is working as designed) but if you put this:

```
unless (++$count % X) { $dbh->commit; $dbh->begin_work; }
```

after the insert, removing the other commit/begin inside the loop, it seems it would do what you want, releasing the locks and getting in the queue for the next set of locks.

Comment: begin_work appears to be working as it should in terms of committing X rows, but what is happening is that while thread 1 is in a transaction thread 2 stops reading the gz input. I was expecting both threads to be building transactions simultaneously and then take turns committing X long transactions. When begin_work/commit are outside the loop each thread runs at 100% cpu but only one thread at a time. When begin_work/commit are inside, multiple threads appear to run at the same time but at about 20% cpu. But I'm guessing maybe top shows 20% when they are actually switching back an forth.

Comment: I think that is expected, especially if you have indexes on the table which will be locked until the commit. There are other factors, like identity keys. If your inserts are incrementing id's as they are inserting you can't expect it to recalculate them on commit because another thread has taken the numbers before it commits. If you had no indexes it might work (but probably not) or if you could physically partition the table (which I doubt SQLite supports) which would allow the table to grow in different places simultaneously.